# How to find out the drivers causing failure of suspend?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, suspend

I own a Dell Inspiron 3542 touchscreen laptop. I have dual booted Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 16.04. I have been using Ubuntu for the last 7 months. 
I am still facing an issue with suspend.

My laptop suspends for 5 times in a row and any attempt to suspend after that fails. So, I can't even say that suspend doesn't work at all on my laptop.

I have turned swappiness to 0 as I have 8 GB RAM and I don't feel the need for it. Also, I have 2 GB Nvidia Graphics Card and Intel® Haswell Mobile Graphics, of which I use the later one. I am using *linux kernel 4.4.0-74-generic*. Using *kernel 4.8* (as mentioned in one of the solutions regarding this matter on AskUbuntu) has done no good.

Is there any way that I can find out which driver is causing problems? Where can I find it and if I find that out, how should I prevent that particular driver from causing any further issues?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry! I have felt that pain.

For me, problem is network. Suspend is not gracefully shutting it down. If you turn off networking before suspend on my Dell PRECISION 5510, it almost always suspends fine.

If you don't find that is fix, problem is very tough. My idea there was to read files in /var/log in time vicinity of fail, but did not gain much so far. You need to post more details, but even then we might not figure it out.

Also, if you can disable Nvidia or other video and use on board graphics, suspend is smoother.

I suspect the "one out of 5" symptom is due to additional services that are activated as time goes by. Perhaps added devices or unfinished jobs.